# How to pass object to Mapper and reducers

Tags: java, hadoop

I have an application run on hadoop. How can I pass the objects to the mappers and reducers so as to process the data. For example, I declare a FieldFilter object for filter the rows processed in the Mappers. The filters contains many filter rules which are specified by users. So, I am wondering how can I pass the filters and rules to the Mappers and Reducers?
My idea is to serialize the objects into String,  pass around the string by configure, re-then construct the object by the string. But seems not good for me! any other approaches?
thanks!

```
public class FieldFilter  {      
private final ArrayList<FieldFilterRule> rules = new ArrayList<FieldFilterRule>();

public FieldFilter addRule(FieldFilterRule ... rules) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
        this.rules.add(rules[i]);
        rules[i].setFieldFilter(this);
    }
    return this;
}    }
```

Comment: You didn't accept any answer to your questions.

Comment: "didn't accept any answer" ?? I am asking question here.  why did u said i didn't accept any question. Two weird replies!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize FieldFilter and [put](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/file_system_shell.html#put) it in HDFS and later read it in the mapper/reducer functions using the HDFS API. If you have a large cluster, then you might want to increase the [replication factor](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/file_system_shell.html#setrep) which is defaulted to 3 for the serialized FieldFilter class, since a larger number of mapper and reader tasks would be reading the serialized FieldFilter class.

If new MapReduce API is used then the serialized FieldFilter file can be read in [Mapper.setup()](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#setup%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context%29) function. This is called during the initialization of the map task. Could not find something similar for the old MapReduce API.

You can also consider using [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to distribute the serialized FieldFilter class to the different nodes.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `setClass()` in the `Configuration` as you can see [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#setClass%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29). You can, then instantiate your class by `newInstance()`. Remember to have the instantiating made in the `setup()` method of the mapper/reducer, so that you don't instantiate the filter every time map/reduce methods are invoked. Good luck.

--Edit. I should add that you have access to the configuration through context, and that is how you will get the class you need. There is a `getClass()` method in the configuration api.